# Which tables should I exclude from a backup?

Tags: 8, backups

As a fan of svelte sql backups I've successfully used, for several years [this bash script](https://gist.github.com/kyleskrinak/8175724) for backing up my Drupal site's databases. By excluding "noisy" tables, I've seen remarkable reduction in the size of the resulting sql file. I am so confident of it, I nearly used it for my Drupal 8 project. However, I presume the schema has undergone some rather significant changes.

Here are the following tables my current script excludes, expressed as a grep pattern:

```
echo "Starting to dump the table data."
TABLES2=`echo "$TABLES" | grep -Ev "^(accesslog|cache.*|flood|search_.*|semaphore|sessions|feeds_log|watchdog)$"`
mysqldump --complete-insert --disable-keys --single-transaction --no-create-info -u ${USER} --password=${PASS} -h ${HOST} ${DB} ${TABLES2} >> ${DB}.${DATE}.sql
```

I'm curious how Drupal 8 changes which tables are safe for exclusion. Note that I'd rather err on the "safe" side. So, for example, sessions (as I understand them in D7) have limited value for backup, but that's for my general application. Your mileage may vary. Also, sorry for the unresponsive table, but there is apparently a row length limit on code posts.

```
| table name:                  | backup? | | table name:                  | backup? |  
| batch                        | Yes     | | node__comment                | Yes     |  
| block_content                | Yes     | | node__field_image            | Yes     |  
| block_content__body          | Yes     | | node__field_tags             | Yes     |  
| block_content_field_data     | Yes     | | node_access                  | Yes     |  
| block_content_field_revision | Yes     | | node_field_data              | Yes     |  
| block_content_revision       | Yes     | | node_field_revision          | Yes     |  
| block_content_revision__body | Yes     | | node_revision                | Yes     |  
| cache_bootstrap              | No      | | node_revision__body          | Yes     |  
| cache_config                 | No      | | node_revision__comment       | Yes     |  
| cache_container              | No      | | node_revision__field_image   | Yes     |  
| cache_data                   | No      | | node_revision__field_tags    | Yes     |  
| cache_default                | No      | | queue                        | Yes     |  
| cache_discovery              | No      | | router                       | Yes     |  
| cache_dynamic_page_cache     | No      | | search_dataset               | Yes     |  
| cache_entity                 | No      | | search_index                 | Yes     |  
| cache_menu                   | No      | | search_total                 | Yes     |  
| cache_render                 | No      | | semaphore                    | Yes     |  
| cache_toolbar                | No      | | sequences                    | Yes     |  
| cachetags                    | No      | | sessions                     | Yes     |  
| comment                      | Yes     | | shortcut                     | Yes     |  
| comment__comment_body        | Yes     | | shortcut_field_data          | Yes     |  
| comment_entity_statistics    | Yes     | | shortcut_set_users           | Yes     |  
| comment_field_data           | Yes     | | taxonomy_index               | Yes     |  
| config                       | Yes     | | taxonomy_term_data           | Yes     |  
| file_managed                 | Yes     | | taxonomy_term_field_data     | Yes     |  
| file_usage                   | Yes     | | taxonomy_term_hierarchy      | Yes     |  
| flood                        | Yes     | | url_alias                    | Yes     |  
| history                      | Yes     | | user__roles                  | Yes     |  
| key_value                    | Yes     | | user__user_picture           | Yes     |  
| key_value_expire             | Yes     | | users                        | Yes     |  
| menu_link_content            | Yes     | | users_data                   | Yes     |  
| menu_link_content_data       | Yes     | | users_field_data             | Yes     |  
| menu_tree                    | Yes     | | watchdog                     | No      |  
| node                         | Yes     | 
| node__body                   | Yes     |
```

Answer (score 3):

I would exclude batch, anything starting with cache_, flood, queue, sessions, sequences, semaphore, watchdog, although one may argue about the batch, flood, queue, sequences and semaphore tables.

Also don't forget to export their schema.

Comment: queue, and sequences shouldn't be excluded. A specific site might not need it for much, but for some modules, queue is important, and losing it might result in losing processing data. sequence is used for db_next_id(), losing it might result in errors if drupal is trying to re-use already used ID's. I think most sites also don't want to lose their user sessions?