# Make Backup & Migrate backups smaller in size

Tags: 7, backups

I have a 2MB upload cap on my school's server and get an error from backup and migrate that it cannot restore the file.

Is there any way the backups from [backup and migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module be compressed in some way and upload them when are needed?

I often take a backup before making new changes on the site and revert to the last one if I make a mistake or get an error, so ideally all files(DB and Directory) need to still be backed up...

Comment: backup_migrate compresses db_dump per default.

Comment: For some odd unknown reason, for me, when I use backup and migrate with Chrome browser the backups are way bigger than if I do them using Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup & Migrate module by default backs up all the data that is in your database. That includes cache_%, watchdog, and other tables data that is not essential for a backup. By excluding data that lives in those tables from your backup (Advanced Backup settings) you can save a great deal of MB.
Read more about tables recommended for exclusion here -[Backup and Migrate exclusion recommendations?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58739/backup-and-migrate-exclusion-recommendations).

Comment: Perfect! - What does flood, history, queue mean in that answer?

Comment: Flood table holds bruteforce login attempts. History table holds  'last viewed' timestamp of the specified node for current user. Queue table stores tasks that need to be run periodically in sequentially-ordered lists.